# Query running fine in SQLPlus but will not run in Toad when connected to the same database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, toad

I am new to Toad, SQLPlus and Oracle. I am attempting to run the following query using the UTL_SMTP package.

```
DECLARE
   v_From       VARCHAR2(80) := 'noreply@myemail.com';
   v_Recipient  VARCHAR2(80) := 'MyEmail@myemail.com';
   v_Subject    VARCHAR2(80) := 'Test with attachment';
   v_Mail_Host  VARCHAR2(30) := 'smtpserver.mycompany.com';
   v_Mail_Conn  utl_smtp.Connection;
   crlf         VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
BEGIN
  v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);
  utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);
  utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);
  utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);
  utl_smtp.Data(v_Mail_Conn,
    'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||

    'From: '   || v_From || crlf ||
    'Subject: '|| v_Subject || crlf ||
    'To: '     || v_Recipient || crlf ||

    'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| crlf ||    -- Use MIME mail standard
    'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| crlf ||
    ' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| crlf ||
    crlf ||

    '-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
    'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
    'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'|| crlf ||
    crlf ||
    'some message text'|| crlf ||    -- Message body
    'more message text'|| crlf ||
    crlf ||

    '-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
    'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
    ' name="excel.csv"'|| crlf ||
    'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| crlf ||
    'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf ||
    ' filename="TextFile.txt"'|| crlf ||
    crlf ||
    'Hello World'|| crlf ||    -- Content of attachment
    crlf ||

    '-------SECBOUND--'            -- End MIME mail
  );

  utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail: '||sqlerrm);
END;
/
```

If I run the package in SQL Plus (Connect / as SYSDBA), it runs fine and I receive the email with the attachment.

If I run the package in Toad (Connected as SYSTEM), I receive the following error message.

```
[Error] ORA-06550: line 6, column 17:
PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_SMTP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 17:
```

I am running on a local Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Version 11.2.0.2.0 64-bit

Comment: Format your error message too, please, and try to use the same user as you used before

Comment: Do you mean attempt to connect to Toad using SYSDBA? or connect to SQLPlus as SYSTEM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the privileges on the package?  These are the privileges on a default 12c installation:

```
select grantee, privilege from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'UTL_SMTP';

GRANTEE      PRIVILEGE
-------      ---------
PUBLIC       EXECUTE
APEX_040200  EXECUTE
```

If that PUBLIC grant is revoked then even SYSTEM cannot use the package.  You could fix this by logging in as SYS and executing `grant execute on sys.utl_smtp to public;`.  If the grant was revoked you may want to find out why.  Some organisations may have a policy against using the package, or may require it to be granted to a specific user.

Also, consider using the newer, simpler package, [UTL_MAIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_mail.htm#ARPLS384).